# Is the "hardware" tag useful? (And should we kill it?)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-naming

Tag [hardware](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) is currently described as

> Physical equipment, such as camera bodies, lenses, accessories, as well as the electronics inside of them. Excludes firmware or other software.

which would make it a *very* big tag, encompassing the existing top-ten tags [lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lens), [equipment-recommendation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-recommendation), [flash](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash) (probably), and [dslr](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dslr) (often). That seems a little silly.

If you look at the [frequent questions in this tag](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware), or the [top voted](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware?sort=votes&pageSize=50), they really have little in common. This does not seem to be a useful tag. Should we kill it?

Comment: Looking through some questions, they could be retagged with camera-body, intervalometer, battery etc.

Comment: @MikeW A lot of them already _are_ also tagged with something more specific.

Comment: @MikeW or another mod — looks like a few upvotes and no objection. Can you kill it? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't burned a tag before: from what I can tell we need to remove it from all questions first? I went through a few questions and removed the tag, but I don't want to bump everything to the first page all at once.

Comment: @MikeW I don't know either. I was under the impression that mods could kill it without editing each one. (A mere mortal can edit each one by hand, which will remove it, but that's very tedious, obviously.)

Comment: I'm slowly removing or changing the tags on the last dozen of these.  Not wanting to spam the front page.

Comment: @MikeW I noticed — thanks!

Comment: Last Q modified, tag should disappear within 24 hrs.

Comment: Thank you, MikeW!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion: merge it into [computer-hardware](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-hardware), and remove it from any questions where that doesn't apply.